# How do i adjust the margin of an imageView according to it's shape?

Tags: android

I have a imageView like this:
[Primary Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTH9h.png)

I want a this imageView margin like this:
 [Desired Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUJJf.jpg)

Can this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this a while back actually, the best options I know of are to create your own shape using a `Path` or you could add a few shapes to a Pane of some sort and get a relatively similar shape like [so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTc6y.png)